# Write to multiple files based on name, in C

Tags: c, algorithm, file

The code below works and writes all logs to one fixed file:

```
    snprintf(filename, 128, "/var/log/api_record.log");

    fp = fopen(filename, "a+");

    if(fp){
        PLIST_FOR_EACH_SAFE(&temp, record, tmp, list){
            PLIST_DEL(&temp, &record->list);
            fprintf(fp, "%.*s\n", record->buflen, record->buf);
            free(record->buf);
            free(record);
        }
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Now I'm trying to get, say, host_name, and write each record to a different file, named by the record's host_name.

```
    if(fp){
        PLIST_FOR_EACH_SAFE(&temp, record, tmp, list){
            PLIST_DEL(&temp, &record->list);
            host_name = record->meta;
            fprintf(fp, "%.*s\n", record->buflen, record->buf); // The question is what's the fp?
            free(record->buf);
            free(record);
        }
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to maintain the fp's here. I can open and close a file with the desired filename with each record, like below, but it's costly. (do one fopen() per iteration of the loop)

```
    snprintf(filename, 128, "/var/log/%s.log", host_name);

    fp = fopen(filename, "a+");
```

Or possibly, traverse through the records as a preprocessing step and open the host_name named files beforehand, then map the host_name's to the fps through some hashmap? But that also sounds quite ugly.

How can I efficiently do this?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: In this case I suggest just opening and closing the file each time through the loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks, @Barmar